# Result from Search Console and Google Analytics were not tally

Tags: google, google-analytics, google-search-console

Did you found that the overall *click*, *impression*, etc from **Google Search Console** was not tally the result shown in **Google Analytics** under user behavior (time, duration etc)

So what is the main caused to this problem?